# Choppy Audio while using Ubuntu Studio

Tags: sound, 17.04, ubuntu-studio

I've used Kubuntu 16.04.x LTS most recently and Ubuntu 14.04.x LTS and had great success with my Intel NUC.

I've had audio problems before, but I was always able to fix them by looking at other people's post.   Not this time.

I recently installed Ubuntu Studio 17.04 and I have choppy audio.

This version has pulse audio and ALSA, plus all the JACK layers...

I don't see any troubleshooting steps that are relevant to Ubunutu Studio 17.04.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

By the way, I am using my HDMI (as I always have) to provide the audio and I did update with Intel's open-source drivers that match Ubuntu 17.04...

~Eric

Comment: Are you trying to do pro audio work? Ubuntu Studio uses JACK by default, with RT priority, and it sounds like the system you're running it on may have issues with that, which causes buffer overruns/underruns (choppy audio). If you're not doing pro audio work, I'd suggest not using Ubuntu Studio. If you are doing pro audio work, you're going to need to adjust the jackd settings (buffer size, number of buffers) to be able to run reliably on that hardware, though then the latency may still be too high for pro audio work.

Comment: In addition, what audio card ? choppy with recording or playback ? with what application ?

Comment: I am not doing pro audio work.  However, I like to play with JACK, MIDI, guitar effects.
I really just saw it as something new to try with the RT kernel.  

The audio in this case is what's built onto the Intel NUC board, but in this specific case, the HDMI out is handling the audio so it is my understanding that the video card is therefore handling the audio.

I get choppy audio watching g YouTube in the default browser... Firefox, I think.

I disabled all powermanagement in BIOS to avoid CPU scaling issues already, so I dont think that is the problem either.

Comment: I am having the same problems with Ubuntu Gnome 17.04...   Choppy Audio still...

I am not sure what do it... I used to have this issue with Kubuntu and Ubuntu, but there were some settings that needed changing... I just can't remember what they were or where I found them...  

Does anyone have any idea?

This is my hardware on my intel NUC:
00:03.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller [8086:0a0c] (rev 09)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller [8086:9c20] (rev 04)

Comment: I am still having this problem even with straight up UBUNTU 16.04 LTS...

The analog audio works fine... it's just the audio coming out of the HDMI interface is choppy...

It's choppy with ALL applications... even with doing a SINE wave test using "speaker-test"